# VirtualHost's behind an nginx reverse proxy fail to resolve properly

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I have a load balancer pair in front of 4 web servers which run nginx on port 80 and proxy to apache on port 8081 for non-static content like php code. I'm running several domains in this configuration. When I hit the domain on 80 for static content, it works fine. Nginx returns what it should. When I go to a PHP page, it always hits the default virtual host.

When I instead visit port 8081 on a php page through the load balancers it servers both php pages and static content properly.

It appears that nginx isn't properly passing off the domains to apache for it to determine what to serve. Where in my config should I be looking for this error or am I misunderstanding what is happening?

Here is my nginx proxy_params contents:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

My server blocks include this code:

```
  location ~ /\. { 
    deny all; 
  }

  location ~.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso|ico)$ {
    expires 7d;
    try_files $uri @apache;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
  }

  location @apache {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
  }
```

Comment: Any clues here > https://www.codementor.io/devops/tutorial/devops-tutorial-nginx-reverse-proxy

My first thought was you'd need a location block for php with the fastcgi_pass defined, which that page seems to suggest

Comment: The fastcgi_pass is in the backend nginx config which I'm using apache for. Apache is handling the PHP without any problems so I don't think that is the issue. Please do correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. The webservers are running nginx, they are also running apache. nginx is caching static content (from apache) and should be passing php to apache to deal with? If that's the case I'd expect to see a fastcgi in the nginx location block

Comment: No, they are passing requests for anything non-static to apache to deal with. If it isn't an image, video, audio or plain text file with an extension indicated by the second location piece it is passed, via the proxy_pass directive(in location / block) to apache on port 8081. Even if is one of those things and it fails to find it in the file structure, it still passes it to apache (the location @apache) which possibly will be able to find it by some htaccess magic or something. The first location block just makes sure nginx doesn't hand out .htaccess, .git, .gitignore and other hidden files.

Comment: What I'm doing can be seen in this documentation without the use of fastcgi: http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

The proxy_params file is not included in the configuration by some sort of default include like I assumed. I've corrected the problem by adding include /etc/nginx/proxy_params to each of my locations using proxy_pass. That "proxy_set_header Host $http_host;" thing is critical.

I'd welcome a cleaner solution if anyone has one that allows me to set those in the config once instead of each time. If you can give me that, I'll give you credit.

Here is my resulting location blocks in each server block:

```
location ~ /\.  { deny all; }

# Serve up the static files through nginx 
# This provides speed improvements
location ~.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso|ico)$ {
  expires 7d;
  try_files $uri @apache;
}

# Try it in the local Apache on port 8081
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
  include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}

location @apache {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
  include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, I just thought that file included 'examples'. I've always done effectively what you've done with the include but I define the proxy_set_header settings per site